# Conemu alternative mode in far

Tags: conemu, far

I've got problem with alternative mode displaying in FAR manager. When switching to it with Win+A or lock icon in menu it displays nothing. It begun after one of the updates of the conemu.

Conemu version is 160914 stable
Far version is 3.0.4455 x64

Conemu plugin in FAR is avaliable and works fine

Comment: Alternative buffer is empty until first issued command. Type "dir" for example.

Comment: It stays empty even after big logs

Comment: Run: `ConEmu.exe -basic -run {Far}` and type `dir`

Comment: hm... It worked. As far as I understood it's some settings brokes output. Maybe you can suggest which one?

Comment: UPDATE: Ok, I found it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With the help of Maximus I found that after update the setting *Inject ConEmuHk* in Settings->Features tab was unchecked. So this was an issue